# aspell exited with signal Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: osx, ispell

I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on Mac Mavericks (Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0). When I run `ispell` command I get the error as in the title. I cannot do spell check. Anybody has a hint?

---

This is the part of my .emacs that regards ispell:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")
(setq ispell-program-name "aspell"
      ispell-dictionary "english"
      ispell-dictionary-alist
      (let ((default '("[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "[']" nil
                       ("-B" "-d" "english" "--dict-dir"
                        "/Library/Application Support/cocoAspell/aspell6-en-6.0-0")
                       nil iso-8859-1)))
        `((nil ,@default)
          ("english" ,@default))))
```

Comment: Found [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.macintosh.osx/1591) from googling; that link provides few options to fix this known issue.

Comment: fwiw: I have tried unsuccessfully several times since 1998 or so to get aspell to work. In theory, it is a drop-in replacement (better?) for ispell. Consider removing aspell and installing the older ispell. ispell has never failed for me. If you're working with core installs on MacOS and don't want to muck with Apple's offerings, it may be the case that when both ispell and aspell are installed, the emacsian invocation of ispell will trump to ispell (have never tested with both installed simultaneously).

Comment: @ericx the weird thing is that I think it was working a while ago, but then I haven't used it for some time and I can't say what I changed in the configuration of mac. I think the reason I choose aspell was that it can do the spell-check on the fly, can't it?

Comment: @kaushalmodi yeah, the fact is that those instructions are not detailed enough for me, and they refer to aquamacs rather then emacs

Comment: @ericx I installed ispell and flyspell, and put flyspell in autoload. Now ispell highlights words as incorrect only if I pass with the cursor on them :(

Comment: I haven't used MacOS since 2000 or so. The success I've had with ispell is based solely on FreeBSD with nothing except ispell installed. However, "it just does the right thing" with little or no fuss on my part. I have no knowledge of your particular errors.